# Any Neon equivalent for RISC V?

Tags: arm, porting, xilinx, neon, riscv

I'm trying to port an ARM library to RISC-V. Source code includes references to arm_neon.h. The RISC-V toolchain does not contain any NEON sources, so, I was wondering if any equivalent exists.

Moreover, any resource on porting ARM libraries to RISC-V?

Comment: there is none...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends on what you mean by "equivalent".

RISC-V doesn't really have SIMD **yet**.  Work on an extension, the [RISC-V V specification](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-v-spec) is ongoing, and AFAICT (from an outsider's perspective) it's getting pretty close.  The API is probably going to be more like SVE than NEON, but if you're just asking about a SIMD API for RISC-V, that's probably your best bet.

NEON also supports 64-bit vectors, which is pretty rare.  MMX kind of supports them, but nobody really uses MMX anymore and Intel doesn't really add new functionality which operates on 64-bit vectors.  If 64-bit vectors are your thing, you might be more interested in the [RISC-V P specification](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-p-spec).  It's not as far along, so you'll likely be waiting longer for hardware support.

If what you care about is matching the API so you don't have to manually port your code, your best bet is probably one of my projects, [SIMD Everywhere (SIMDe)](https://github.com/simd-everywhere/simde/) (so obviously take the recommendation with a grain of salt).  Work on implementing NEON is ongoing, but we're currently a bit more than halfway through it.  There aren't any RISC-V specific implementations yet (we'll probably start trying to add support after compilers start to support it), but since there is no generally available hardware which implements the V spec it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent is RISC-V Vector Extension (RVV).

Check porting NEON to RVV.

Some RISC-V ip vendors (such as SiFive, StarFive) have already provide this feature.